# Why can an MS account be not recognized on a specific computer?

Tags: microsoft-account

My daughter has an MS account set by her school. She logs into it by Chrome on her Android phone or on her notebook (Windows 10), both without problems, both for a month. But today, when we tried to login her on our family computer, either by Chrome or by Edge, in the same Windows 10, we were and we are getting the same

> "That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different account or
> get a new one."

message. I had already checked for excessive spaces or other invisible symbols (the account name was typed by hand, letter by letter, and simply hasn't them).

Could it be connected to the fact, that that computer is normally used for several different MS account logins?

MS help is hapless, as usual.